# Use of undefined constant LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED

Tags: php, centos, libxml2

I have just deployed some DOM Manipulation code to our staging server and am getting the error:

```
[PHP notice] Use of undefined constant LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED - assumed 'LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED'
```

I have no issues on my desktop using WAMP and cannot find any modules that appear to be related.

Our Centos 6 server appears to be using PHP version 5.4.34 with libxml2-2.7.6-1 installed.

I have searched our `php.ini` file and there is no mention of 'libxml' and `phpinfo()` gives me the following section for lib_xml:

```
libxml

libXML support => active
libXML Compiled Version => 2.7.6
libXML Loaded Version => 20706
libXML streams => enabled
```

Why would this constant be undefined?

Comment: @PaulCrovella Yep, saw that immediately after posting the question.. Add it as an answer with a link to the docs and I'll accept. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your libxml version is *almost* there:

From http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php#constant.libxml-html-noimplied:

> Only available in Libxml >= 2.7.7